# Where might the following quote about circular reasoning and land ownership be from?

Tags: quote-source

> "I accept only one notion of land property. Namely, 'I am doing my
> stuff here, therefore I am here".
>
> "But this means," he responded, "you can break into any place and stay
> there, using this rule."
>
> "There is another rule, though. Right to act in its most natural
> sense, 'I am here, therefore I am doing my stuff here."
>
> "But do not these rules put together become circular reasoning?"
>
> "Of course, they do," I put my head closer to him, "and this is
> exactly that rare case when circular reasoning is not only sufficient,
> but is necessary."
>
> "But why is that? Circular reasoning never was a correct argument."
>
> "There are many circular things happening in nature. Life forms, for
> example, exist only in order to produce new life forms or to
> prolongate their own lifetime. Is there any reason to say this can't
> be the case for reason itself? Why must reasoning not be circular?"

This quote is part of a question on [Philosophy Stack Exchange](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/55574/is-circular-reasoning-always-a-fallacy) about circular reasoning. I’d like to know where it comes from. I believe looking at the edit history there were accidental typos in the Cyrillic alphabet, like the word “эгe”. The OP’s username begins with “rus”, not sure if a reference to Russian. The OP commented that they made some edits to the translation.

My guess is this is more or less an original translation of a possibly Slavic text. Can anyone recognize which one?

(As I was writing this, I came to believe that this is an original text by the OP, but am going ahead and posting this anyway.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about an original work. In comments to both the question at Philosophy Stack Exchange and the answers, the OP there makes clear that this is something they are writing: "[I later argue ..."](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/55574/is-circular-reasoning-always-a-fallacy#comment149891_55574), ["in the case of my dialog"](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/55574/is-circular-reasoning-always-a-fallacy#comment149890_55585), etc.

Comment: See [Are questions asking to critique the OP's original work on-topic?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1295/are-questions-asking-to-critique-the-ops-work-on-topic). The fact that the OP is someone on Philosophy, rather than the OP of this question here, does not make the question any more on-topic. Nor does the fact that it's an [tag:identification-request] rather than a request for critique.

Comment: Have you asked the OP, in a comment on Philosophy.SE, where they got it from?